# Blazor: There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, blazor

Blazor doesn't seem to grasp my generic type constraints when using `@typeparam`.
The following setup gives a compilation error:

`error CS0314: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyObject<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable<T>'.`

MyObject.cs

```
public class MyObject<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public MyObject(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }
}
```

MyComponent.razor

```
@typeparam T where T : IComparable<T>
<div>
    @MyObject.Value
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MyObject<T> MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

MainComponent.razor

```
<MyComponent MyObject="@value" />

@code {
    private MyObject<decimal> value = new MyObject(21M);
}
```

I know I can add the type parameter explicitly, by doing this:

```
<MyComponent T="decimal" MyObject="@value" />
```

But in the codebase I'm about to write that will get very very cumbersome. It feels like blazor is supposed to be able to implicitly determine the type parameter used in the above example.

Is there a way to make this implicit type determination possible?

I'm using net6.0

Comment: The type needs to be constructed long before Blazor sets any parameters. How would it know what type to pass as `T` to the constructor?

Comment: @maksymiuk I suspect it's because generic type inference doesn't work in this scenario, but the reason Jesse expects this to work is that he's passing in a value with a compile time type argument that satisfies the constraint, but it's not being inferred without being explicit.

Comment: @maksymiuk `value` is of type `MyObject<decimal>`, so it would be obvious that `decimal` is the generic type parameter in this case? At least it would be in 'plain' C#

Answer (score 1):

If `MyObject<decimal> value` was a parameter in the constructor for `MyComponent` then it would make sense that `T` could be implicitly determined. But Blazor needs to construct a new `MyComponent` long before any parameters in the type are actually set. So Blazor would have to know that you set all the parameters necessary for determining all type parameters, which it apparently doesn't do.

And you can see this by putting a breakpoint in the `OnInitialized` function of your component and seeing that `value` will not yet have any value.

[You can see the lifecycle of the component here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Plain C# example:

```
MyComponent c = new MyComponent<decimal>();  // <--- How must Blazor know this is a decimal here?
c.value = new MyObject(21M);
```

Comment: You wouldn't even be able to initialize a generic class if you don't know the generic type parameter compile time. If I remove the generic type constraint `IComparable<T>`, everything works. So what is T in that case then? It must be a decimal, what else? You cannot initialize a generic object if you don't have its type parameter.

Comment: Well if that is true then I am at a loss. Blazor must be smart enough to use the properties to get the constructor `T`, but not smart enough to handle type constraints. You could breakpoint in `OnInitialized` to verify that `value` is not yet set, yet your type `T` should already be `decimal`, unless it uses `Nullable<decimal>` or `object`.